# unable to find nunit assembly for xamarin test cloud in VSTS

Tags: xamarin, nunit, xamarin-test-cloud, azure-pipelines

Hi I am using VSTS for CI. For my Xamarin Android application during the build process it is trying to test the app on cloud, it's failing as it is not able to find nunit.framework.dll file in the project. I am using Nunit Version 2.6.4

The NuGets in the project are included in the output directory but still, I am getting the issue, can you please help me with it?

VSTS: Test Assembly Directory: Solution/Droid.UITests

Error:
Unable to find the nunit.framework.dll in the assembly directory. In Xamarin Studio you may have to right-click on the nunit.framework reference and choose Local Copy for it to be included in the output directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had to remove the old references from the solution's nuget package collection.

Comment: How did you remove the old references ?

Comment: goto the solution file and see where all the nuget packages are being downloaded its generally in a file named 'packages', delete the old reference there.